# Calculating a domain of integration.

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals, 3d

I am going through a practice exam for my calculus course and I found this question :

> Evaluate $\iiint_{G} xy\ d V$ where $G$ is the region bounded by $$x+y+z \leq 1, \quad y \leq x, \quad x \geq 0, \quad y \geq 0, \quad z \geq 0$$

The answer given straight away says $$\int_{0}^{0.5} \int_{x=y}^{x=1-y} \int_{0}^{z=1-x-y} x y d z d x d y$$ without calculating the domain, but it does not seem too obvious to me how it is done. After working through algebra, I can see that you can find $y>0.5$ using the inequalities but by the same logic can't I show $x>1$ instead of $x>1-y$ ? How would I go about intuitively finding these limits? Can it only be done by finding all the intersection points?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to sketch the region of integration to see what is going on with the limits.

On the $xy$ plane you have the base which is the  triangular region between the $x$ axis, the lines $y=x$ and $y=1-x$

The ceiling is the plane $z=1-x-y$ and the floor is the $xy$ plane which is $z=0$

That should have clarified the limits once you have a three dimensional graph to look at it.